# is the {{link}} method depreciated in i18n for rails 3?

Tags: ruby, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3

I used the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543936/rails-i18n-translating-text-with-links-inside) to implement links inside of the language file of my  rails app. Unfortunately it seems, that this doesnt work anymore with rails 3. It just puts out the `{{link}}` as text...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like i18n [deprecated `{{tag}}` and changed it to `%{tag}`](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4525-favor-in-all-code-instead-of-deprecated-as-interpolation-syntax-for-i18n).

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your answer. I tried to use .html_safe function, but unfortunately didn't help... but thanks anyway!

Comment: @Markus, The `html_safe` stuff was a red-herring, or maybe I'm way too tired. Anyway, I updated the answer to what looks like a lot more likely fix.

Comment: Great, thats the solution! Thanks a lot!