# Rails 3, i18n: Interpolating html tags into text

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

My problem is exactly the one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543936/rails-i18n-translating-text-with-links-inside). Only difference: I'm using Rails 3 (3.0.4 exactly), which uses the `%{...}` syntax rather than the old `{{...}}`.

Problem: Rails 3 escapes all tags inside `%{...}` so I cannot interpolate, say, **links** in there.

Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I finally figured it out, you have to use `_html` as a suffix for any yaml-keys, that you do not want html-escaped:

```
paragraph_html: "This is some text with a %{link}"
paragraph_linktext: "really cool link"
```

and then

```
link = link_to t( paragraph_linktext ), "http://www.example.com"
<%= t( paragraph_html, :link => link ) %>
```

and voila, there you have your i18n-ized link.

Answer (score 11):

You can do like this

```
my_translation: "Click to access %{link} page"
```

then:

```
<%= t( my_translation, :link => link_to("Google", "http://google.com") ).html_safe %>
```

And everything will be ok!

Comment: What if the content you're inserting is not html_safe, such as `t("Welcome %{name}, name: content_tag(:strong, current_user.name))` But you don't want the <strong> tags to be escaped.  Thanks!

Comment: It appears that from at least 4.2 onwards, the only way to do this is to use `raw()` on the `String` object returned by the translator functions. Even though [the documentation for ActionView Helper in 4.2.1](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper/translate) claims that the `_html` suffix is used to mark a string as HTML-safe, that is not my experience.