# How to localize link text in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

In my Rails3 app I have:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %>
```

I know how to localize text, but how to localize link text? I defined "sign_out" in tried:

```
<%= link_to t( sign_out ), destroy_user_session_path %>
```

But it generates an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `sign_out'
```

What is the correct syntax?

*PS: It is even more basic than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367705/rails-3-i18n-interpolating-html-tags-into-text), but I could not find any answer.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to t('sign_out'), destroy_user_session_path %>
```

And you must define the key sign_out: in your local yml file after

Answer (score 1):

How about `link_to t("sign_out"), destroy_user_session_path`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to t(:sign_out), destroy_user_session_path %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to t('sign_out'), destroy_user_session_path %>
```

You can check other details [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-translate).