# rails 3 internationalization / localization - embeddings links in translated text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization

I need to embed links in my translated texts.  I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543936/rails-i18n-translating-text-with-links-inside), but it doesn't seem to work in rails 3 anymore as the html tags don't get rendered properly.

Anyone knows how to get this done in rails 3?

Update:
Apparently, the html tags can be escaped by using the html_safe method.  But does anyone know if there's another way to solve this problem without using html_safe?

I would like to avoid unescaping my html tags if possible, b/c I've encountered a situation where I have to pass in a text field into my translation, and I would like to avoid unescaping any strings that are user inputted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `{{url}}` to `%{url}` and you should be good to go.

### Update

Ok, thanks, that's important information about what "doesn't work" means :)  So, you need to call the `html_safe` method on your call to `link_to`, eg.

```
link_to(t("log_in_href"), login_path).html_safe
```

This will tell Rails to render the HTML, not escaped.

Comment: Yeah I've done that, that's not the problem.  The variable gets passed in, but the html tags still render as is.

Comment: E.g. "Don't have a paypal account? Get one here" becomes "Don't have a Paypal Account? Get one <a href="http://www.paypal.com" target="_blank">here</a>."

Comment: The html_safe solves the problem for links, but I just encountered a situation where I have to pass in a full text field as a variable into the translation text, and I don't feel comfortable doing html_safe on that. Is there another way around this without using html_safe?

Comment: Split up whatever you're passing in so you *are* comfortable `html_safe`ing the HTML part of it.

Comment: Yeah, or I'll probably find some ways to sanitize it first. Thanks.

Comment: Just encountered the issue of rendering links/other html inside localized strings. As a note for other people: the html_safe should be called on the localized string not the link_to. E.g. t('.name', :link => root_path).html_safe