# Rails I18n: Better way of interpolating links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, dry

Is there a cleaner, content_tag-ish way of doing this? (I don't want HTML in my YML)

en.yml:

```
expert_security_advice: "Go <a href='{{url}}'>here</a> for expert security advice."
```

layout.html.erb:

```
<%= t(:expert_security_advice, :url => "http://www.getsafeonline.org") %>
```

Comment: It does it's job, it's simple... ok it seems ugly but it's straight.

Comment: It may just have been an example, but “here“ is really bad link text (for numerous reasons including search engines and blind users)

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails i18n - translating text with links inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543936/rails-i18n-translating-text-with-links-inside)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I could come up with:

en.yml:

```
expert_security_advice: "Go *[here] for expert security advice."
```

layout.html.erb:

```
<%= translate_with_link(:expert_security_advice, "http://www.getsafeonline.org") %>
```

application_helper.rb:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

def translate_with_link(key, *urls)
  urls.inject(I18n.t(key)) { |s, url|
    s.sub(/\*\[(.+?)\]/, content_tag(:a, $1, :href => url))
  }
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That gsub is looking kinda nasty though. Maybe it could be simplified somehow with content_tag(:a, $1, href="#{url}"?

Comment: Seems ** is also taken by Markdown.

Comment: Maybe we could also make this thing handle multiple URLs?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/sub): Special match variables such as &$, will not refer to the current match. Use either block form or '\1'. Replace $1 with '\1' and you're good to go.

Comment: By the way man, any chance you're up for hire for a short gig?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this. I'm afraid I'm not looking for work atm.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't a cleaner way of dealing with this. If you want pull the `url` out of the string then you're stuck breaking the sentence into four pieces:

1. `"Go`.
2. `<a href="{{url}}">...</a>`
3. `'here'`
4. `'for expert security advice.'`

These four pieces are easy to put back together in English but the order might change in other languages and that can change the capitalization of *here* and cause other problems. To get it right, you'd have to structure things like this:

```
here        = "<a href=\"#{url}\">#{t(:expert_security_advice_here)}</a>"
whole_thing = t(:expert_security_advice, :here => here)
```

and the two separate strings in your YAML:

```
expert_security_advice_here: "here"
expert_security_advice: "Go {{here}} for expert security advice."
```

You'd also have to tell the translators that those two pieces of text go together.

If that sort of thing seems cleaner to you then go for it but I wouldn't worry about small bits of HTML in text that needs to be translated, any translator worth talking to will be able to handle it. Never try to take shortcuts with I18N/L10N issues, they will always lead you astray and cause problems: non-DRY code (WET code?) is always better than broken code.

---

As an aside, I'd recommend that you drop the standard Rails I18N string handling tools in favor of [gettext](https://github.com/grosser/gettext_i18n_rails), keeping everything synchronized with gettext is much easier and the code ends up being much easier to read.