# haml, link_to helper, and I18n in the same sentence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, haml, yaml

Here is the markup I'm trying to get:

```
<p>View more <a href="/clinics/integratedclinic">clinic information</a> 
including physicians, locations, directions, documents, and more.</p>
```

I'm using haml, yaml, and Rails (oh my!). In order to do this with localization, I have to have this yaml:

```
en:
  view_more: View more
  link: clinic information
  details: including physicians, locations, directions, documents, and more.
```

And put my haml on 3 lines like:

```
%p
  = I18n.t('view_more')
  = link_to I18n.t('link'), clinic
  = I18n.t('details')
```

It seems like there's got to be a better way. The first issue is that this wouldn't work for languages with different syntax, in which the link might occur at the end of the sentence because of grammatical word order.

Isn't there a way to pass the link in as a parameter? But then I have to interpolate it in the yaml, and maybe put markup in there? That doesn't seem great, either. Is there an elegant way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is using [Localized Views](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#localized-views). At first replace

```
%p
  = I18n.t('view_more')
  = link_to I18n.t('link'), clinic
  = I18n.t('details')
```

with

```
= render partial: 'view_more', locals: { url: some_path }
```

Subsequently you can create a file `_view_more.en.html.haml` with

```
%p
  View more
  = link_to 'clinic information', url
  including physicians, locations, directions, documents, and more.
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. I didn't know about localized views. I'll circle back and mark this correct if no one else offers up anything stellar.

Comment: The gotcha here is that if you have to change the link, you change it in two places. Don't suppose there's any way around that.

Comment: I've updated the code of my answer so you don't have to change the URL twice.

Answer (score 1):

You find some more ideas at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543936/rails-i18n-translating-text-with-links-inside). My favourite is to use just two translations together.

In your locale:

```
  view_more_details_html: "View more %{link} including physicians, locations, directions, documents, and more."
  link: "clinic information"
```

And just one view:

```
%p
  = I18n.t('view_more_details_html', link: link_to(I18n.t('link'), clinic))
```

Comment: This is a 2 1/2 year old question, but thanks for that answer! I actually like that better than the one I accepted.

Comment: @nickcoxdotme The answer is not just for you, but for all the other readers as well. I found this question second on Google.