# HAML using t method from model for multi languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, liquid

I have a haml file which is used to translate text into multi language as below

```
%ul
    %li
      %a
        %i{'ng-class' => '[button.css_class]'}
        %span t ('{{button.label}}')
```

The button.label retreives from the model, but it did not work.
If I change the code as below:

```
    %ul
    %li
      %a
        %i{'ng-class' => '[button.css_class]'}
        %span t ('save')
```

it works fine.

I need to use button.label for dynamical name.

Any approach to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: `#{}` is used to evaluate ruby code in views, so try `#{button.label}`

Comment: thanks, I used #{ t('{{button.lable}}')} it works fine

Comment: glad it worked for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [haml, link\_to helper, and I18n in the same sentence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001268/haml-link-to-helper-and-i18n-in-the-same-sentence)