# Rails I18n word as a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

In my I18n file i have the following translation:

```
reservation:
  please_accept: "Please accept regulation"
```

And in my view i'm using it in the following way:

```
= t('reservation.please_accept')
```

Now I want to the word "regulation" be a link to some action in my app. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean something like this `<%= link_to(t("Regulation"), your_path)) %>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails i18n - translating text with links inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543936/rails-i18n-translating-text-with-links-inside)

Answer (score 0):

Answer for my question:

```
= t('reservation.please_accept', href: link_to(t('reservation.regulation_word'), '#', "data-toggle" => "modal", 'data-target' => "##{@car.id}")).html_safe

reservation:
    regulation_word: "regulamin"
    please_accept: "Proszę zaakceptować %{href} wypożyczalni"
```