# eRB and multiple statements syntax?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have the following in an *html.erb* file, using `link_to` to get a hyperlink and `t()` to internationalize my text.  But it looks very clunky:

```
<p><%= t('session.new_user') %><%= link_to(t('session.signup_now'), signup_path) %></p>
```

Splitting onto multiple lines seems wrong since the text will all appear on the same line on screen but is there a better syntax to avoid the two consecutive `<%= %>` blocks?

Comment: Ach! Sharing the valid eRB would help!

    `<p><%= t('session.new_user') %><%= link_to t('session.signup_now'), signup_path %></p>`

Comment: You could pass the link as an argument: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2544107/477037

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go for line breaks:

```
<p>
  <%= t('session.new_user') %>
  <%= link_to t('session.signup_now'), signup_path %>
</p>
```

or you could set variables before the actual code

```
<% new_user_text = t('session.new_user') %>
<% link = link_to t('session.signup_now'), signup_path %>
<p><%= new_user_text %><%= link %></p>
```

or you could set instance variables in the controller. I wouldn't like that for view stuff like this.

**Extra**: if you like tidy code you may like haml

```
%p
  = t('session.new_user')
  = link_to t('session.signup_now'), signup_path
```

now it is actualle readable!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hyphen before the closing tag to prevent a newline being appended to the output.

```
<% ... -%>
```

Please note that this feature is Rails specific.