# rails i18n - translating text with multiple links inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I like to have multiple links inside one yml-key.

This post [rails i18n - translating text with links inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543936/rails-i18n-translating-text-with-links-inside) covers one link inside a yaml-key and i'm wondering if it's possible to have multiple links:

Something like:

```
# en.yml
additional_terms: additional terms
data_privacy: data privacy terms
gtc_link: GTCs
terms_html: "By accepting the GTCs %{gtc_link}, you confirm that you agree to the %{data_privacy} and %{additional_terms} of the Wirecard payment option."
```

In my View:

```
 <div class="terms">
 <%= t('view.user.account.terms_html',
   {
     gtc_link: link_to(t('pages.imprint.gtc'),"/pdf/agb_#{I18n.locale}.pdf", { target: '_blank' }
   },
   {
     data_privacy: link_to(t('view.account.data_privacy'),"https://www.wirecardbank.de/privacy-documents/datenschutzhinweis-fur-die-wirecard-zahlarten/", { target: '_blank' }
   },
   {
     additional_terms: link_to(t('view.account.additional_terms'),"https://www.wirecardbank.de/privacy-documents/datenschutzhinweis-fur-die-wirecard-zahlarten/", { target: '_blank' }
   },
    )) %>
 </div>
```

Comment: get rid of the `{}` inside of `t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it like this?

```
<div class="terms">
  <%= t('view.user.account.terms_html',
        gtc_link: link_to(t('pages.imprint.gtc'),"/pdf/agb_# {I18n.locale}.pdf", { target: '_blank' }),
        data_privacy: link_to(t('view.account.data_privacy'),"https://www.wirecardbank.de/privacy-documents/datenschutzhinweis-fur-die-wirecard-zahlarten/", { target: '_blank' }),
        additional_terms: link_to(t('view.account.additional_terms'),"https://www.wirecardbank.de/privacy-documents/datenschutzhinweis-fur-die-wirecard-zahlarten/", { target: '_blank' })
      ) %>
</div>
```